# ProGuard - Ignore JNA library

Tags: java, proguard

So, I have a problem with ProGuard (GUI, not the console).

I have an application, and it has the JNA library. And I need to obfuscate my application and I need to DO NOT OBFUSCATE JNA, that is, just ignore this library, I found a Stack Overflow question similar to mine, only it used a console and I use the GUI.

Is it possible to ignore JNA in a GUI?

Comment: Btw sorry if text have some grammar mistakes :) Is it translator

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.  Have you tried it?